# xcape slow in GNOME 3

Tags: gnome, 18.04, shortcut-keys, remapping

I'm using xcape to get left <kbd>Alt</kbd> to emit escape when pressed & released alone (among other remappings). Unfortunately since upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 I've noticed that it's significantly laggier than it was in Unity (16.04). This means (for example) if I press left <kbd>Alt</kbd> = escape in vim to leave insert mode then quickly press <kbd>u</kbd> to undo, the xcape lag will cause the u and ESC to get swapped and I'll instead insert a u before leaving insert mode.

I've tried

1. Using KDE plasma on Ubuntu 18.04. xcape seems as fast as usual there but I'd prefer not to switch window managers just for this issue. (I have a lot of other hacks that I don't feel like setting up again in KDE).
2. Testing out xcape on a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04. The issue seems to occur there too.
3. Pulling, compiling, and using the latest master from https://github.com/alols/xcape. Still laggy.
4. Disabling `/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/keyboard` and `/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/a11y-keyboard`. (I don't know what they do but my thought was that there must be some heavy keyboard abstraction layer in GNOME that maybe I can cut through).

This is a niche issue to be sure but I'm still hoping that someone's figured out a solution to this.

Comment: There's some talk in here about it: https://github.com/alols/xcape/issues/109?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container